# Límite en cantidad de elif

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas. Estoy usando 51 anidaciones de `elif:` en Python y creo que no se está recorriendo todo. Hay algún límite teórico en la cantidad de anidaciones por bloque `if` en Python 3?

Comment: En general no es buena idea tener 51 bloques elif, hace muy confuso el código. Podrías estructurar mejor el código

Comment: La verdad, no me he preocupado por eso ya que el código tiene suficientes comentarios y saltos de línea para poder entenderse, pero gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Tal vez [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090395/is-there-a-limit-to-else-if-statements) respuesta del sitio en inglés te ayude

Comment: Y tiene relación con Python aun siendo de JavaScript?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con anidaciones de `elif`? ¿Te refieres a bloques `if-elif` anidados o un solo bloque `if-elif` con 51 `elif`? Si son bloques realmente anidados es una barbaridad y en Python que aboga por la legibilidad aún más, cuando se pasan de los 4-5 niveles anidación /identación hay que considerar refactorizar el código, porque por norma general se puede hacer otra aproximación más legible. Si es un solo bloque con un `if` y 54 `elif` no hay problema como muestra la respuesta de @FelipeM (recordando que **en cuanto un `elif` se cumpla el resto no son evaluados siquiera**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la especificación del lenguaje Python, puedes tener entre `0` e infinitos bloques `elif`

En la [Documentación de elif de Python](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#elif), el bloque :  `( "elif" expression ":" suite )*`  significa que lo que está entre paréntesis - es decir la expresión `elif : tu código` - puede ir `0` o muchas veces indicado por el `*`.

Aunque tengas la posibilidad de escribir tantos bloques `elif` como quieras, no es una práctica recomendada.